# Set the properties of a base class in c#

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have what I think is a simple noob question.

In the CMS i'm using there's a method Product.Get(4545) which get's all the properties for the built in Product class.

I wish to extend the product class with this, so I guess this is what I would do on at basic level.

```
public class ExtendedProduct : Product
{
    public ExtendedProduct ()
    {

    }

    public string Foo { get; set; }
}
```

But how do I set the base product to be the result of Product.Get(4545) so all those properties are set? I was thinking something like (and this doesn't work) base = Product.Get(4545) or similar.

The Product class has literally 100s of properties already in it. For example.

I could call

```
var prod = Product.Get(22);
var price = prod.Price; //22.99
```

Updating my thoughs from from the responses below, I was thinking of

```
var prod = ExtendedProduct.Get(22); static method that sets the base class properties?
var price = prod.Price; //22.99
var foo  = prod.Foo
```

Whilst writing this I think the easiest thing is to pass Product into the contstructor of ExtendedProduct and have a property of Product. But is that being lazy?

I was hoping to avoid a scenario where I would call `new ExtendedProduct(product).Product.Price` and just call `new ExtendedProduct(product).Price`

```
public class ExtendedProduct
{
    public ExtendedProduct (Product product)
    {
        this.Product = product;
    }
    
    public Product Product { get; internal set; }

    public string Foo { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What does `Product` class look like?

Comment: Create a new static Get method in the ExtendedProduct type, call Product.Get inside, create a new instance of ExtendedProduct, and then copy all the properties over. Anyone of these parts might already be available to you in the base class but without seeing it here, we can't tell you how to do it different.

Comment: "I wish to extend this" - assuming the "this" in question is the _method_ (ie. that's the only part of `Product` you want to expose in some way), you probably don't want to _inherit_ from `Product`

Comment: Without seeing the CMS `Get` method it's hard to say. Unless the CMS understands your extended class it's unlikely to be able to save or load it from the database. If this item exists only in your code you may be better off using composition rather than inheritance.

Comment: Have updated the question with answers.

Comment: How does the existing `Product.Get` method work? To do what you want, you're going to have to re-implement it. If it's fairly simply (e.g. it just calls `new Product(n)` and returns it) then it is a simple matter to extend it. Otherwise it could be pretty difficult.

Comment: @JohnWu It's pretty complicated. It's a built in static from the CMS that does all sorts (get's the Product entity, populates new values etc etc, very difficult to follow the code). I guess I should stick with my 'lazy' solution then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty hard to do exactly what you want. I suggest reversing it instead. Retrieve the regular `Product` object the normal way, and use an extension method to convert it to the extended object as needed.

```
static class ExtensionMethods
{
    static public ExtendedProduct ToExtendedProduct(this Product source)
    {
        return new ExtendedProduct(source);
    }
}
```

Now you can do this:

```
var prod = Product.Get(22); 
var price = prod.Price; 
var foo  = prod.ToExtendedProduct().Foo;
```

Comment: I've gone  a slightly different route now, however this helped massively with my understanding.